# How to get jenkins test report link from surefire-reports testng-results.xml?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

My current Jenkins runs multiple builds. Each build/run would create its own testng-results.xml (target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml)

I check results from the HTML report available on the Jenkins job homepage (which would show the report only of the latest build/run).

How do I get the report of a previous build from the corresponding testng-results.xml because I want to dump the report links for every build by extracting them from the testng-results.xml

I couldn't find any entry in the testng-results.xml that points to the path/place where the corresponding test report for that run/build resides.

Anyway to get this?

Comment: Are you using HTML Report Publisher? If yes then there is the setting which says should override existing report or keep with each build.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Archive Artifacts. Then your results get saved on the Jenkins Master. They will not be lost when client Workspace get scraped